# x-ms-window command pulling and linking screen resolution's

Tags: javascript, php, html, visual-studio-2013

Okay so This is my code. Im trying to get it to embed a webpage based on the screen resolution's for windows 8.1 applications but how do i recall the variables in my .js script.

```
<body>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = screen.width;
    var y = screen.height;
    document.getElementById('insert').width = x;
    document.getElementById('insert').height = y;
}
</script>
<x-ms-webview id="insert" src="http://subgamer.com" width=0 height=0 ></x-ms-webview>
```

Please explain along with code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly recommend using a library like JQuery as it makes your code much neater and is very powerful. This can simply be done using the following line of code: (for a web connected site, if it is for local use you would need to download the file locally)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Then it would be a simple matter of inserting the following code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#insert').height($(window).height());
    $('#insert').width($(window).width());
});
```

The `$(function(){  });` tells it to run when the page has loaded.
The `$('#insert')` selects the element with id of 'insert' and the rest is just asigning the height and width values.

if the window will be resized at any point then you could put that inside a function

```
function resizeInsert(){
    $('#insert').height($(window).height());
    $('#insert').width($(window).width());
}
```

and call it when the page is loaded and when the screen is resized, like so:

```
$(function(){
    resizeInsert();
});

$( window ).resize(function() {
    resizeInsert();
});
```

This way your `'insert'` element will always remain the full size of the window.